# Why won't Groovy see JAVA_HOME correctly?

Tags: groovy, puppet

I'm trying to install Groovy via Puppet on SUSE SLES 11 SP2.  I have the Groovy files installed, but now I need to set the environment variables.  I'm using a shell script to set the values and when I echo the values, they are correct.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/myapplication/mypath/jdk1.6.0_30
```

When I run the command "groovy -version" I get this error: `/bin/javaAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute: /myapplication/mypath/jdk1.6.0_30.`
That's not a typo, that's actually the output I get! :)

This is the correct path to my java installation.  Why is "/bin/java" replacing the "J" in "JAVA_HOME"?  I searched /bin and /usr/bin and neither directory has a java directory.

If I set the values from the command line on the server, everything works fine.

Here is my shell script:

```
# groovy.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/myapplication/mypath/jdk1.6.0_30
export GROOVY_HOME=/myapplication/mypath/groovy-2.0.7
export PATH=$PATH:/myapplication/mypath/groovy-2.0.7/bin
```

Here is the snippet from my puppet module:

```
$groovy_sh = "/etc/profile.d/groovy.sh"

file { $groovy_sh:
ensure => present,
source => "puppet:///modules/groovy/groovy.sh",
owner => "myuser",
group => "mygroup",
mode => 777,
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be a Windows/Unix linefeed issue.  I inluded the dos2unix package in my module and everything started working as expected.